# Rockrider btwin 6.2 swingarm pivot

Tags: mountain-bike, full-suspension

I have a Rockrider btwin 6.2 full-suspension mountain bike. After 3 years of use, most of the parts were shot. I replaced most of them but also noticed that the swingarm pivot seems to have a seemingly unsafe amount of play. It surely seems to move more than 3-4mm. Before i try to open than and see what's up, is there anyone who has had a similar problem? or who know whether the bearings are standard/available and if at all it's easy/possible to fix it? considering this isn't a very expensive mountain bike. Would still like to keep it though, serves the commute to office and the outdoors on weekends. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is check all the pivot bolts are tight. If that doesn't fix it, figure out where the play is. Is it in the swingarm pivot, or the shock bushings? You can figure it out by holding onto each joint in turn and moving the swingarm. You shoukld be able to feel which part is loose. If it's been like it for a while, it might be all three points.

Once you find the source of the problem, I guess you'll need to go to your local bike shop (or the place you got the bike - Decathlon?) and see if they're able to source the spare parts. Shock bushings should be easy enough to get, but I don't know about the pivot hardware. You'd need to open it up and have a look what's in there!

Comment: Thanks, Decathlon it is then! it's the last part i haven't replaced on this machine!

Comment: Update: I took it apart, apparently nothing was wrong, the bearings hadn't ceased, the bushes were still reasonable, what the problem was was that the bolts holding the bushes are like one fully threaded stud and two threaded end caps which tighten on the stud. This whole complicated arrangement had come a bit lose. Took it apart tightened everything and assembled everything with some bearing cease (not worth buying anti cease, thread lock not necessary too i suppose), now the play is down to a minimum. Thanks for the encouragement :)